# Is there an easy way to assert that an element is NOT present?

Tags: c#, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have tried a few different things but I get an element not found exception each time... Which means that the test *should* pass but I'm not sure how to capitalize on that. I've tried:

```cs
public void AssertDeleteLogBookCategoryButtonIsNotPresent()
{
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => _elements.deleteLogBookCategoryButton.Click());
}
```

and also:

```
public void AssertDeleteLogBookCategoryButtonIsNotPresent()
{
    Assert.That(!_elements.deleteLogBookCategoryButton.Displayed);
}
```

...but both throw the exception while it is finding the element that it shouldn't find. Advice please!

Comment: try to use the exact type of the exception being thrown within `Assert.Throws<TheException>`, instead of just `Exception`.

Comment: Why don't you help youself with some Nuget library, such as [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/collections/) or [Shouldly](https://docs.shouldly.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the assertion on `Driver.FindElements().Any()`.
This will not throw exception because `FindElements()` method returns a list of elements matching the passed locator. So, in case of no match (element not found) this will return an empty list so that the entire expression will return `Boolean` `False` while in case of presence of such element the result will be `Boolean` `True`.

Comment: This looks super promising. Only issue is that I declare all of my page elements as individual IWebElements, rather than By. Is there a way around this, or will I have to declare this element as a By instead?

Comment: Well, personally I hate and never use initially defining elements as `IWebElements`. Using `By` is much, much preferably (to me) and even not just `By` but even defining Strings XPath locators so it will be possible to concatenate strings, pass parameters in them etc. But these are my personal choices :)

Comment: OK, so I'm trying that instead but for some reason it now won't let me use .Displayed! Am I being dense? This is what I was trying to do:  Assert.That(_driver.FindElements(By.Id(_elements.showAllCheckbox)).Displayed);

Comment: Sure. You trying to apply the `Displayed` method on a list of web elements while this method is applicable on a single web element object...

Comment: I actually went with Assert.IsEmpty(_driver.FindElements(By.Id(_elements.showAllCheckbox))); in the end. Asserting that the list itself was empty. Thanks for your help, I wouldn't have got here without you

Comment: You first need to validate element presence - if the list is not empty and then, if you still need to assert the element is displayed - get the `[0]` element from the received list and apply `Displayed` method on it